# How to get a particular attribute from XML element in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have something like the following XML in a column of a table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container>
  <param name="paramA" value="valueA" />
  <param name="paramB" value="valueB" />
  ...
</container>
```

I am trying to get the valueB part out of the XML via TSQL

So far I am getting the right node, but now I can not figure out how to get the attribute.

```
select xmlCol.query('/container/param[@name="paramB"]') from LogTable
```

I figure I could just add /@value to the end, but then SQL tells me attributes have to be part of a node. I can find a lot of examples for selecting the child nodes attributes, but nothing on the sibling atributes (if that is the right term).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try using the `.value` function instead of `.query`:

```
SELECT 
  xmlCol.value('(/container/param[@name="paramB"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM  
  LogTable
```

The XPath expression could potentially return a list of nodes, therefore you need to add a `[1]` to that potential list to tell SQL Server to use the first of those entries (and yes - that list is 1-based - not 0-based). As second parameter, you need to specify what type the value should be converted to - just guessing here.

Marc

Comment: I have dynamic nodes in the field like 
     <l>
       <r id="2" />
       <r id="5" />
     </l>
By using the your give query I am able to read according to index. Means When I'll give index as a 1, it will display 2 and when i'll give index 2, it will display 5 but I requires both nodes. so would you please suggest me how to do it !

Comment: I am having trouble using this for a boolean. I tried using 'boolean' and 'System.Boolean' as second params and received an error. If i do varchar it returns all nulls.  My xml line looks like: <Property Name="param" Value="True" Type="System.Boolean" />

Comment: @Zeb: SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` type - it has `BIT` - or you might just need to read it as an `INT` and then process it further

Comment: what if , we are not sure about path of attribute in xml. but sure about xml tag.? means i have xml column but each xml is different and i am sure about my xml contains <ash> tags then how can we take the value of it..?

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the the actual structure of your xml, it may be useful to put a view over it to make it easier to consume using 'regular' sql eg

```
CREATE VIEW vwLogTable
AS
SELECT
    c.p.value('@name', 'varchar(10)') name,
    c.p.value('@value', 'varchar(10)') value
FROM
    LogTable
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/container/param') c(p)
GO


-- now you can get all values for paramB as...
SELECT value FROM vwLogTable WHERE name = 'paramB'
```

Comment: Why does xmlCol.value('(/container/param[@name="paramB"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  not work for me but just .value('@value', 'vharchar(50)') does work? Hmmmmm.