# SQL XPath query looking for node value by attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I refer to [How to get a particular attribute from XML element in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561102/how-to-get-a-particular-attribute-from-xml-element-in-sql-server).

I do not have a particular attribute with the value of the node in it, but rather the I am looking for the value of the node depending on which attribute I am looking for.

I am selecting from an XML column in a table in SQL, but for simplicity sake, I can provide the following example:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = CONVERT(XML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alert>
   <hits>
      <elem name="hit">
         <elem name="scoreFactors">
            <elem name="scoreFactors">
               <elem name="factorId">FactorID 1</elem>
               <elem name="factorDesc">FactorDesc 1</elem>
               <elem name="factorValue">FactorValue 1</elem>
               <elem name="factorScore">FactorScore 1</elem>
               <elem name="factorImpact">FactorImpact 1</elem>
            </elem>
            <elem name="scoreFactors">
               <elem name="factorId">FactorID 2</elem>
               <elem name="factorDesc">FactorDesc 2</elem>
               <elem name="factorValue">FactorValue 2</elem>
               <elem name="factorScore">FactorScore 2</elem>
               <elem name="factorImpact">FactorImpact 2</elem>
            </elem>
         </elem>
       </elem>
   </hits>
</alert>')

SELECT @xml.value('(/alert/hits/elem/elem[@name="factorDesc"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

All I am getting back is a `NULL` value, but I am expecting 2 rows with `FactorDesc 1` and `FactorDesc 2` as values, respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't need that `CONVERT`. You can assign a string constant directly to a variable of type `xml`: `DECLARE @xml xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><alert></alert>'`

Comment: cool thanks! I did not know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That attribute you're looking for is on the **fourth** level of `<elem>` - so you need to use this XPath:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/alert/hits/elem/elem/elem/elem[@name="factorDesc"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

or alternatively use this XPath (but **beware**: this can be a **killer** of performance, if your XML has a lot of `<elem>` nodes! You've been warned!)

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/alert/hits//elem[@name="factorDesc"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

**Update:** if you want **all** the nodes with the `factorDesc` name, you could use something like:

```
;WITH Shredded AS
(
    SELECT 
        ElemName = xc.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),
        ElemValue = xc.value('.', 'varchar(50)') 
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('/alert/hits//elem') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT *
FROM Shredded
WHERE Shredded.ElemName = 'factorDesc'
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I need to specify all the levels down - or use `//`. Your second example is almost what I need, except that it only returns the first elem where the name attribute is factorDesc. Why isn't it returning a list of all elems where the name attribute is factorDesc?

Comment: @MrThursday: it's returning just the first one - **because you tell it to**  by specifying that `[1]` ...

Comment: @MrThursday: updated my response to handle *all* nodes, too

Answer (score 1):

Search in all elem's:

```
SELECT
    t.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('(alert/hits//elem[@name="factorDesc"])') AS t(t)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for except for one thing: If I had to change that query to be able to select all elem's out of an xml column, what would it look like?

Comment: @MrThursday out of xml column? can you give an example? i'm afaid, i don't understand

Comment: I guess it would be a nested select, where I would replace `@xml` with the column name? For the purpouses of my question, I supplied the example xml as variable. but in a more practical sense the xml would come from a a column in a table and would not be hard coded.

Comment: a query could look like this : SELECT t1.xmlColum FROM table1 t1

Comment: @MrThursday, oh, it will look the same, just replace `@xml` with column name